# JS/jQuery - Check if element has all classes in array

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, requirejs

I have a `<ul>` of items
Then I have an array of classes to filter.
Now I want to loop through all `<li>` and show only the items that contain **all** of the classes in the array and hide all the others.

How can I do that?

Code so far (untested):

JS

```
define([
    "jquery"
], function($){
    "use strict";

    function main(config, element) {

        $('.filter-option').on('change', function (event) {

            const activeFilters = $('.filter-option:checked');

            if (!activeFilters) {
                $('.product').forEach(function(item) {
                    item.show();
                });
            } else {
                $('.product').forEach(function(item) {
                    //if item has all classes from activeFilters id's show else hide
                });
            }
        });
    }
    return main;
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="filter-box">
    <h3>Size</h3>
    <input type="checkbox" class="filter-option" id="size-s" name="size-s">
    <label for="size-s" class="filter-option-label">Small</label>
    <input type="checkbox" class="filter-option" id="size-m" name="size-m">
    <label for="size-m" class="filter-option-label">Medium</label>
    <input type="checkbox" class="filter-option" id="size-l" name="size-l">
    <label for="size-l" class="filter-option-label">Large</label>
    <h3>Colour</h3>
    <input type="checkbox" class="filter-option" id="color-white" name="color-white">
    <label for="color-white" class="filter-option-label">White</label>
    <input type="checkbox" class="filter-option" id="color-red" name="color-red">
    <label for="color-red" class="filter-option-label">Red</label>
    <input type="checkbox" class="filter-option" id="color-blue" name="color-blue">
    <label for="color-blue" class="filter-option-label">Blue</label>
</div>
<ul id="product-list">
    <li class="product color-red size-l">Red Large</li>
    <li class="product color-red size-m">Red Medium</li>
    <li class="product color-red size-s">Red Small</li>
    <li class="product color-blue size-l">Blue Large</li>
    <li class="product color-blue size-m">Blue Medium</li>
    <li class="product color-blue size-s">Blue Small</li>
    <li class="product color-white size-l">White Large</li>
    <li class="product color-white size-m">White Medium</li>
    <li class="product color-white size-s">White Small</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Please show us all relevant code, Html, css, jquery.

Comment: included my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have something like this and want a VanillaJS solution:

```html
<div id="list-container">
    <ul>
        <li class="example">One</li>
        <li class="example another-class">Two</li>
        <li class="example">Three</li>
        <li class="example">Four</li>
        <li class="example">Five</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

You can iterate the `<li>` elements and check the classes like this:

```js
// Required classes array
let reqClasses = ['example', 'another-class'];

// Function to check if the element has the required classes
const hasClasses = (item) => {
   var s = true;
   
   reqClasses.forEach((classname) => {
      if (!item.classList.contains(classname) && s) {
         s = false;
      }
   });
  
   return s;
}

// We get the <li> elements
let list = document
   .getElementById("list-container")
   .querySelectorAll('li');

// We call the function on each element and toggle visibility depending on the return
list.forEach((item) => {
   if (!hasClasses(item)) {
      item.style.display = 'none';
   }
});
```

Comment: You are missing a `)` in the last `forEach`. Second, when I run your code it hides all the `li`

Comment: @Carsten you're right, I updated the source with the proper one.

Comment: Wouldn't it be possible to drop the 's' and just iterate through the required classes and return false as soon as one doesn't fit? Since I need all classes to match?

Also would it be possible to just:
1. hide everything
2. jQuery Select everything with all  required classes
3. show selection

I'll try your code though, thanks!

Comment: Ended up with this, which is based on your answer: https://jsfiddle.net/Chazlol/mqg851tc/3/

Answer (score 1):

Solved it like this now:

**Update:** Had to adjust the filters from AND to OR.
For that the accepted answer was the most helpful.
Still think this approach is suitable for what I initially wanted to do,
 so I'll keep it here in case someone else finds it to be helpful.

For the inital question

> "How to check if element has all classes in array"

and with using jQuery, a simple solution would be:

1. Loop through array of classes and concatenate them to a string.
2. Select that string with jQuery
3. Returns only matching elements

```js
$('.filter-option').on('change', function (event) {
  const activeFilters = $('.filter-option:checked');
  let classString = "";
  
  if (activeFilters.length === 0) {
    $('.product').show();
  } else {
    $('.product').hide();
    activeFilters.each((index, filter) => {
      classString += "." + filter.id;
    });
    $(classString).show();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="filter-box">
    <h3>Size</h3>
    <input type="checkbox" class="filter-option" id="size-s" name="size-s">
    <label for="size-s" class="filter-option-label">Small</label>
    <input type="checkbox" class="filter-option" id="size-m" name="size-m">
    <label for="size-m" class="filter-option-label">Medium</label>
    <input type="checkbox" class="filter-option" id="size-l" name="size-l">
    <label for="size-l" class="filter-option-label">Large</label>
    <h3>Colour</h3>
    <input type="checkbox" class="filter-option" id="color-white" name="color-white">
    <label for="color-white" class="filter-option-label">White</label>
    <input type="checkbox" class="filter-option" id="color-red" name="color-red">
    <label for="color-red" class="filter-option-label">Red</label>
    <input type="checkbox" class="filter-option" id="color-blue" name="color-blue">
    <label for="color-blue" class="filter-option-label">Blue</label>
</div>
<ul id="product-list">
    <li class="product color-red size-l">Red Large</li>
    <li class="product color-red size-m">Red Medium</li>
    <li class="product color-red size-s">Red Small</li>
    <li class="product color-blue size-l">Blue Large</li>
    <li class="product color-blue size-m">Blue Medium</li>
    <li class="product color-blue size-s">Blue Small</li>
    <li class="product color-white size-l">White Large</li>
    <li class="product color-white size-m">White Medium</li>
    <li class="product color-white size-s">White Small</li>
</ul>
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Chazlol/3zuaey0x/1/

Answer (score 0):

You are probably better serverd by using `<input type "radio">` elements "radio buttons" instead of `inpout type="checkbox">` elements, as these will only allow one of the same-named elements to be checked. The script for making elements visible or invisible is then straightforward:

```js
const ul=document.querySelector('#product-list');
document.querySelector('.filter-box').onchange=ev=>{
  let siz=document.querySelector('[name=size]:checked');
  let col=document.querySelector('[name=colour]:checked');
  [...ul.children].filter(li=>
     li.style.display= siz&&li.classList.contains(siz.value)
                    && col&&li.classList.contains(col.value) ? 'block': 'none' 
  );
}
```

```html
<div class="filter-box">
    <h3>Size</h3>
    <label><input type="radio" name="size" value="size-s">small</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="size" value="size-m">medium</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="size" value="size-l">large</label>
    <h3>Colour</h3>
    <label><input type="radio" name="colour" value="color-white">white</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="colour" value="color-red">red</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="colour" value="color-blue">blue</label>
</div>

<ul id="product-list">
    <li class="product color-red size-l">Red Large</li>
    <li class="product color-red size-m">Red Medium</li>
    <li class="product color-red size-s">Red Small</li>
    <li class="product color-blue size-l">Blue Large</li>
    <li class="product color-blue size-m">Blue Medium</li>
    <li class="product color-blue size-s">Blue Small</li>
    <li class="product color-white size-l">White Large</li>
    <li class="product color-white size-m">White Medium</li>
    <li class="product color-white size-s">White Small</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use a combination of [Array.prototype.every()](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) and JQuery [.hasClass()](https://api.jquery.com/hasClass/)

```js
const classList = ['a', 'b'];

function checkClassList($el, classList){
  return classList.every((c) => $el.hasClass(c));
}

console.log(checkClassList($("#id1"), classList))
console.log(checkClassList($("#id2"), classList))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="id1" class="a b"></ul>
<ul id="id2" class="a"></ul>
```